# Javascript: Read, Add and Display form values

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a web app that takes user input as numbers in 15 text or number inputs on a html form, it should then add these values together and display the total in a label elsewhere on the page.

I have 15 inputs with the class name "takings" and a label with the ID "TotalLabel" on the page.

```
function getsum () {
    var rows = document.getElementsByClassName("takings");
    var total = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        var val = parseFloat(rows[i].value);
        total += val;
    }

    var label = document.getElementById("TotalLabel");
    label.value = total;
    alert(parseFloat(total));
}

window.onload = getsum;
```

The alert is only in place for debugging purposes and it appears that the variable total is still set to zero at the end of the script. I also need to make the `getsum()` function fire every time a user enters data in any of the fields with class "takings".

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

So you need to add change events to all of the elements and call `getsum`

```js
function getsum () {
    var rows = document.getElementsByClassName("takings");
    var total = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        var val = parseFloat(rows[i].value);
        total += val;
    }

    var label = document.getElementById("TotalLabel");
    label.value = total;
}

window.onload = getsum;

//Example showing how to add one event listener to the page and listen for change events
//The following works in modern browsers, not all browsers support addEventListener, target, and classList. 
document.body.addEventListener("change", function(evt) {  
   var targ = evt.target;
   if(targ.classList.contains("takings")) {
      getsum();
   }

});
```

```css
label { display: block; }
```

```html
<label>1</label><input type="text" class="takings" value="0"/>
<label>2</label><input type="text" class="takings" value="0"/>
<label>3</label><input type="text" class="takings" value="0"/>
<label>4</label><input type="text" class="takings" value="0"/>
<label>5</label><input type="text" class="takings" value="0"/>
<label>Total:</label><input type="text" id="TotalLabel" value="0" readonly/>
```

Comment: Or `input` event handlers.

Answer (score 0):

To have your `getSum()` function fire for all of those elements, you can use Javascript to add an `onchange` event to all elements with the required class name

```
var input = document.getElementsByClassName("takings"); 
for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) { 
   input[i].onchange = getSum;
}
```

Other than that, I don't see any visible errors in your `getSum()` function.

Comment: @SterlingArcher That is true, I took this from another method I used where my function required `this` as a parameter.

Comment: Nothing wrong with an anonymous function either, don't worry

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an EventListener to your input fields and call getsum, for example

```
var a = document.getElementsByClassName("takings");
for (var i = 0;i<a.length;i++){
    addEventListener('keyup',getsum);
}
```

Please note that a label has innerHTML, not a value:

```
label.innerHTML = total;
```

With your actual function, you will get NaN as a result as long as not all the inputs have a value, so you will need to add

```
 if (val) {
      total += val;
    }
```

to your for loop.

**Full working code:**

```
function getsum(){
    var rows = document.getElementsByClassName("takings");
    var total = 0;

for (var i =0; i < rows.length; i++){

    var val = parseFloat(rows[i].value);
    if (val) {
    console.log(val);
    total += val;
    }}
var label = document.getElementById("TotalLabel");
label.innerHTML = total;

}



var a = document.getElementsByClassName("takings");
for (var i = 0;i<a.length;i++){
    this.addEventListener('keyup',getsum);
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/5zjomm7a/1)